# wals info values 125 126 127 128

Tags: linguistic-typology

if I give examples in german french and turkish in terms of wals Info values 125 / 126/ 127/128 , can someone explain why they are balanced, deranked, or both?

Comment: What are your examples?

Comment: Are you asking what the meanings of these terms is, or what facts support the claim? If the former, did you read the articles; if the latter, did you check the source grammars?

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the corresponding WALS articles have been read, I'll give a short explanation for why the German value is 'both' for feature 125, which can be easily carried over to the other values as well.

Purposive clauses in German can (i.a.) be formed with the '*zu* infintive', as in (1), or with a finite clause introduced by the preposition *damit* ('such that'), as in (2).

```
(1) Du  lernst um  froh  zu sein.
    you learn  for happy to be
   `You learn in order to be happy.'

(2) Du lernst, damit     du  froh  bist.
    you learn  such-that you happy are
   `You learn, such that you are happy.'
```

So in (1), the deranked (because infinite) form is used to form a purposive clause whereas in (2) a balanced (because finite) form is used. You can see from the translations why English also has the 'both' value for feature 125. In Turkish, on the other hand, there are no finite purposive clauses (most likely converbial constructions will be used in Turkish). In French, you only have the *pour V-INF* construction.

So, you can just look at these values through the finite/non-finite lense to begin with.